# router-flux background image issue

Tags: reactjs, image, background

I have set a background for the application. I want to edit the registration and login pages using router-flux, but when I create the router structure, the background picture creates a problem. What should I do?

https://hizliresim.com/IpMm8D

https://hizliresim.com/MI0gnV

Comment: _What should I do?_...debug it to solve it. Or i have to elaborate on this as "Find the root cause if you fail to solve it, then post a good question with actual code part which is causing issues".

Comment: I'm using react-native-router-flux. I will link the Signup and Login screens. I use a picture in the application as a background. After setting up the router structure, the fields created for user registration do not appear. Nothing showing as an error in Console

https://hizliresim.com/nBgcPQ
https://hizliresim.com/dUhpo8